# PHP GET Method without output

Tags: php, curl

What I am trying to do is open a url and pass variables using PHP,

Everytime I use the cURL method it opens the page and displays the output and won't follow the redirects afterwards.

The HttpRequest is not found.

What can I do?

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

For privacy issues I cant post what the url is but thats the code thats giving me the problem when It curls the page it actually displays what it's curling.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: How are you calling CURL? Note that it doesn't follow redirects by default.

Comment: I can't post 5 pages because their are includes all I need to do is open a url but it wont let me....

Comment: Major flaw: you've turned ON returntransfers, but don't actually CAPTURE the returned data. It should be `$data = curl_exec($ch);`